# MATLAB: Creating an Array/Vector from one dimension of a 4D matrix.

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a 4D vector with size(N_square) = (64,32,87,1460)
And I need to filter the overall N_square for values less than 0. However, I then need to take the pressure values(3rd Dimension) corresponding to those N^2 < 0 values and make a histogram of them. I have already figured out how to filter the values of N^2 the way I want to, now I am trying to grab that 3rd dimension with the correct values and make a new matrix with just the pressure values. Here is my code that filter the N^2.

```
N_square(N_square > 0) = 0);
N_square = abs(N_square);
```

The problem with this part as well is that I end up with a vector of all the values I want, and then a crap ton of zeros.

Any thoughts or ideas? I really need to get this done soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
X = ones(2,3,4,5);

X(:,:,2,:) = -1;
X(:,:,4,:) = -1;
X(1,1,3,1) = -1;
X(1,1,1,1) = -1;

[I1,I2,I3,I4]=ind2sub(size(X), find(X<0));

hist(I3)
```

MATLAB matrices have two kind of indices, subscript and [linear indices](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html#buf0c2r-8). Subscript indices are the ones you are used to like `X(i1,i2,i3,i4)` but you could also write `X(k)` which is a linear index. Calling `find(X<0)` gives the linear indices of all entries in `X` less than zero. `ind2sub()` converts the linear to subscript indices. `hist(I3)` then plots the distribution of the third index.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are doing with the code? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: I added an explanation in the answer.

Comment: Holy crap....thank you so much! I never knew that about matlab! You're my new favorite person. If you are ever in Louisville Kentucky, you'll get the finest meal this town has to offer.

Comment: That's nice :) but unlikely with me being on the other side of the planet. You could [mark this as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) though.

Comment: I do have another question though, say I wanted to pick a particular set of data. (ie. I3 at element 57) How would I do that? Is there a way to filter I3 and have the effect go to I1 and I2 as well?

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly, but you could just pick a particular 3rd index like `Y = X(:,:,57,:);` and then call `[I1,I2,I3,I4]=ind2sub(size(Y), find(Y<0));`. This would give you the indices of all values less than zero with `i3==57`. `I3` would only contain multiple `57`.